# Flutter Search Bar with ListView with Checkboxes

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-dependencies, flutter-windows

I want to create a widget like this.
This contains the Textfield, Once type something in the field, It will be sorting the list and show the results below the field. The result list shown below can also have a checkbox field to select multiple items from the result.
Is there any built-in flutter widget that can be useful for this case?
Or any other package to achieve this.

Following is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

I tried with RawAutoComplete widget.

Here is the code.

```dart
   class SearchBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
      const SearchBarDemo({super.key});
    
      static List<String> suggestons = [
        "USA",
        "UK",
        "Uganda",
        "Uruguay",
        "United Arab Emirates"
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: RawAutocomplete(
            optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) {
              if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                return const Iterable<String>.empty();
              } else {
                List<String> matches = <String>[];
                matches.addAll(suggestons);
    
                matches.retainWhere((s) {
                  return s
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                });
                return matches;
              }
            },
            fieldViewBuilder:
                (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
              return TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Search',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8,
                      horizontal: 4), // EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 5),
                  prefixIcon: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 4),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      border: Border(
                        right: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                controller: textEditingController,
                focusNode: focusNode,
                onSubmitted: (String value) {},
              );
            },
            onSelected: (selection) {},
            optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
              return Material(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: options.map((opt) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          onSelected(opt);
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 250,
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: Card(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          opt,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                        ),
                                        Transform.scale(
                                          scale: 0.8,
                                          child: Checkbox(
                                            value: false,
                                            onChanged: (val) {},
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Output of the above code is:
It covers the whole screen and show the result content in center.

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I added the code and screenshot in the description, please check now.

Comment: I think  I will prefer rendering ListVIew with TextFiled changed on this case. Also there is a method `showSearch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the filter logic. Also you may like [SearchDelegate-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html)

```dart
class SearchBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBarDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchBarDemo> createState() => _SearchBarDemoState();
}

class _SearchBarDemoState extends State<SearchBarDemo> {
  static List<String> suggestons = [
    "USA",
    "UK",
    "Uganda",
    "Uruguay",
    "United Arab Emirates"
  ];

  List<String> filterItems = [];
  List<String> checkedItems = [];

  late final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController()
    ..addListener(() {
      /// filter logic will be here
      final text = controller.text.trim();
      filterItems = suggestons
          .where(
              (element) => element.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();

      setState(() {});
    });

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        CupertinoTextField(
          controller: controller,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filterItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final bool isChecked =
                    checkedItems.contains(filterItems[index]);
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  value: isChecked,
                  title: Text("${filterItems[index]}"),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                      checkedItems.remove(filterItems[index]);
                    } else {
                      checkedItems.add(filterItems[index]);
                    }
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented the same solution that you shared. But when I start typing it is not returning any results. Is it working for you? Can you share the output?

Comment: try to type `u` and then move forward, the logic is here startWith

Comment: I tried to log the results and found that the logic is working fine, Only it is not visible below the text field :(

Comment: I just tested on web, working as expected.. do you mean get the items and render after selection is complete?  on that case use `selectedItem` list

Comment: You are right, this is working as expected, There is an overlapping issue that is causing the listview builder hidden.

Comment: As you see in the first screenshot, The list is overlapping on top of the screen, This is pending only.

Comment: you may want [this](https://gist.github.com/yeasin50/cca223f88abb7792d91c52f0fe5361d6)